# CSS Fade in on hover

Tags: css

I'm currently attempting to have a  with an image fade in when I hover over some text using CSS. I've applied the CSS code, but the effect doesn't show; the div appears, but without the fade-in.

Also, I realize that CSS transitions don't really work with IE. If anyone could point me in the right direction of a workaround for that, it would be much appreciated. (:

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: relative;
display: none;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
opacity:0.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
padding: 5px;
left: -1000px;
border: 1px solid gray;
background-color: #fff;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
position: relative;
display: inline;
top: -290px;
left: -25px; 
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);/*position where      
enlarged image should offset horizontally */
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#networking {
width: 200px; 
height: 140px; 
margin-left: 360px; 
top: 115px; 
position: absolute; 
background-color: #613286; 
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
color: #ffffff; 
text-align:center; 
border-radius: 20px; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(14deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(14deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(14deg);
-o-transform: rotate(14deg);
transform: rotate(14deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="networking">
<a class="thumbnail" href="1.5.2experientialstudios.html#down4"><h4>Networking Lounge</h4>    
<span><img src="images/net3.jpg" width="250" /></span></a>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with removing your display rule:

```
.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    position: relative;

    /*display: none; remove this */

    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

As you have opacity 0 you won't need display:none and you can't make a transition between not displayed at all to inlined as they are different types.

And modify this rule:

```
.thumbnail:hover span { /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/

    top: 0px; /* adjust as needed */
    left: -25px; 
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);/*position where      
    enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

(the hover and then span can make it a bit jumpy).

<strike>I also added a ms prefixed version to transitions. It is apparently not useful in this context.</strike>

For IE9 and below you can use jQuery to fade in an element (or simply use vanilla JavaScript to modify the opacity in a setTimeout loop).

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/9rCQv/

Is this what you're after?

Comment: Hi, yes, it works great! Thank you!

Quick question - will the ms-prefixed version work in older versions of IE as well? Or is there a way to have it work on older versions of IE, e.g. IE 8/9?

Comment: @BlissL.Ng it (transition) won't work with IE8 for sure, and I'm not sure about 9+ (I don't have IE9+ so I cannot test), but I suspect it will only work with IE10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still hopefully looking for a way to make this work in IE 8/9 as well, but thank you very much!

Comment: @BlissL.Ng you won't be able to use transitions with IE8 (possibly 9), but check out jQuery and the fadeIn/Out functions (or you can use a vanilla Javascript function to modify the opacity style with a timeout).

Comment: Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 and below do not support transitions via css. Secondly, there is not need to use the -ms-transition prefix. It isnt a proper vendor extension for this rule

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware
Thank you for the information, will look into it!